# Gesture response outside of stack boundary not recieved

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement a re-sizable widget with handles at the corners. The corner handles will be overflow the `Stack` by half of its width/height.

**Issue:** the outer part of handle does not report gesture events while the inner part is working fine.

It is intended or I am doing some thing wrong. If it is intended behavior then what to do next.

sample code

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          body: Transform.translate(
            offset: boxOffset,
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 100.0 - 20.0,
                  top: 100.0 - 20.0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {print("tapped");},
                    child: Container(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter, how can a positioned Widget feel taps outside of its parent Stack area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366761/in-flutter-how-can-a-positioned-widget-feel-taps-outside-of-its-parent-stack-ar)

Answer (score 2):

This is the desired behavior. If widgets could catch pointer events outside of their boundaries; it would be easy to fall into a situation where it's impossible to determine which widget is targeted.

In short, don't use overflow. Refactor your layout to make sure it's well contained inside the bounds of its parent.

Comment: "Refactor your layout to make sure it's well contained inside the bounds of its parent."

What happens when you have widget A and widget B. You want widget A to slide down behind widget B and disappear when the user taps on widget A.
You need a stack to do this.

Comment: Using a Stack doesn't mean that there should be an overflow.

Comment: That's the exact use for a stack though, is to emulate Z-index and move an element independently of the other.

Comment: These still don't imply an overflow. Overflow is almost never wanted in Flutter.

Comment: Can you provide an example without "overflow"?

Comment: I am panning/zooming my Stack and without overflow.visible I'm unable to see the complete widget when I pan/zoom. I'm am also unable to detect a gesture on a widget outside the stack bounds for this slightly different use case.

Comment: @RémiRousselet what if overflow is inevitable?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue then found out about [defer_pointer](https://pub.dev/packages/defer_pointer) package.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a nice package. Thank you.