# Gesture Detector not working having container as child and Positioned as parent

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget tree like this:

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 20,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Positioned(
        right: -10,
        top: -20,
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () {
            print('hello world');
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme.of(context)
                        .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    width: 1.0)),
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
          ),
        ))
  ],
)
```

`GestureDetector` is only working for the region which lies inside the stack boundary  (hence which is visible when clipBehavior is Clip.hardEdge).

How do I make the whole `GestureDetector` work or what could be an alternative approach to stack a clickable widget.

There are a lot of similar questions but I am not able to get the correct approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter, how can a positioned Widget feel taps outside of its parent Stack area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366761/in-flutter-how-can-a-positioned-widget-feel-taps-outside-of-its-parent-stack-ar)

Comment: Just wrap the container with gestureDetector.NO need of potion

Comment: I wanted to create a UI similar to this https://ibb.co/RzLV0dg, And I wanted the second widget in stack to be totally clickable @GHPrakash

Comment: I tested your code. It's working fine. went you click on the second widget (yellow circle) the log printing hello world.@kanwarmanraj

Answer (score 0):

Your GestureDetecture is not working because of the overlapping of the red Container and blue container over each other, I don't know the exact reason

1. but its woking by removing the red container
2. or by wrapping the red with Positioned widget also

Comment: I wanted to create a UI similar to this https://ibb.co/RzLV0dg, And I wanted the second widget in stack to be totally clickable

Comment: `I don't know the exact reason` -> `Stack(`  I think!